# Update query return 1 ,but can't update in database using MSSQL in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress-shortcode

I have used MsSQL remote connection in php and when i retrieved data from database then it is working well , but when i update data then update query return 1 ,but data can'be updated in database.

`$array['Active'] ='1';`

`$array['ExprireDate'] ='2019-08-01';`

`$result = $db->update('Memeber',$array,'Memeber=1');`

Can you tell me what should i do for it ?

Comment: Your code is wordpress?

Comment: yes. I have used in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

According to [wordpress document](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/), condition of update function is an array.

So, let you try:

```
$result = $db->update('Memeber',$array, ['Memeber' =>1]);
```

Comment: It is independent on what database which used.

Comment: I am using mssql ,

   `$handle = mssql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Cannot connect to server"); `

`$db = mssql_select_db($dn_name, $handle) or die("Cannot select database"); `